# VBA To find strings in Column A inside a specific folder contains several types of files

Tags: vba, excel

i need a code to meet the below requirements

1. Column A of an excel sheet contains some strings
2. i will specify a folder to search those strings
3. in that specified folder, there will be sub folders, and several types of files eg : .txt, .c, .xml  etc..

4.i need search the strings one by one in entire folder structure and log all the result  like 
search strings in column A   Howmany occurance in File(s) in B    file locations in C

thank you

the below code will search file names entered in column A and stores the location in B

i tried the below:

Option Explicit

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim i As Long
Dim fld As Folder
Dim c As Range


Sub Find_Path()
   Dim nDirs As Long, nFiles As Long, lSize As Currency
   Dim sDir As String, sSrchString As String, sItem As String
   Dim fldr As FileDialog


111:
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .InitialFileName = "D:\Check\"   'ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
        .Show
           If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "Folder to search is  not selected"
            GoTo 111
           Else
            sDir = .SelectedItems(1)
           End If
  End With

MsgBox "You have selected  : " & sDir, vbInformation

  'Application.Cursor = xlWait
  Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
  Application.StatusBar = "Please wait..."

    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)


     sSrchString = Range("A" & c.Row).Value

     lSize = FindFile(sDir, sSrchString, nDirs, nFiles)       

     If Str(nFiles) = 0 Then

       Range("B" & c.Row).Value = "Not Found in the Folder :   " & sDir

      End If

    Next
Application.Cursor = xlDefault
Application.StatusBar = False

End Sub






This will search for files in folder and sub folders. but i need to search string
```

Comment: Use Google. This isn't the place where you can ask for code without showing you tried something before.

Comment: Sorry, it looked like you hadn't done anything... so, what is missing in your code?

Comment: here the code searches only the file(with extension) names that i enter in column A. i want to search it inside the each files which are under one path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can go through a file... Just add it for every file you want to search in

```
Dim filenum, targetfile, Line
filenum = FreeFile
targetfile = "C:\Mytextfile.txt"
Open targetfile For Input As filenum
Do While Not EOF(filenum)
    Input #filenum, Line
    'if InStr(1, Line, yourSearchString) then 'check if your string is in this line
Loop
Close filenum
```

Comment: Please post it as a comment. This is not an answer.

Comment: This code is fine. but it searches the whole line match. i need it as any where in the line.. thanks for the support

Comment: edited the code... now it searches the SearchString anywhere in the line